# What is the content of OBJ file?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I know that a OBJ file produced after compilation of C/C++ source code in any standard compiler generates OBJ file, which later LINKed with the rest of the required libraries to form the EXEcutable file. I want to know the format/structure of the OBJ file. Please go ahead.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file

Answer (score 6):

C++ Builder (and Delphi) use OMF format obj files. See this [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocatable_Object_Module_Format) for details.

**Additional information:** Microsoft Visual C++ use an incompatible [COFF](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121460), that's why C++ Builder have a utility to convert them.

**See also:** [What's the difference between the OMF and COFF format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966597/whats-the-difference-between-the-omf-and-coff-format)

Answer (score 1):

the .obj file is a format used by Microsoft Compilers and is described in the (Common Object File Format) COFF spec

other compilers use different formats to store object code, e.g. ELF on Linux

Answer (score -1):

Under windows, it'd be a COFF object. Google this file format for a spec. They are linked to produce a PE.