# COFF vs OMF library format on windows

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder

I'm having a hard time finding information about COFF vs OMF libraries. I know that MS is COFF and Embarcadero is OMF, but what about other toolchains? Most information I've found online seems to date from 5 years ago or more, which implies that these issues have been "settled", but how?

Other than Embarcadero, I've discovered Digital Mars requires OMF files, along with the D community and some parts of the Fortran Community (Open Watcom at least). Are there any other notable requirements for OMF libraries?

Also, are there different versions of COFF? Will a VS produced (ie COFF) library work with all windows compilers that support COFF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the OMF and COFF format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966597/whats-the-difference-between-the-omf-and-coff-format)